# Noun Phrases with colons and semicolons

Tags: noun-phrases

Given:

> John was causing obstruction: the act of preventing passage or progress.

Given that the clause after the colon is elaborating on the  head noun 'obstruction', does this mean that the entire sentence is a noun phrase?

If not, are any circumstances where ':' forms a noun phrase?

Does the same reasoning apply to semicolons (';')?

Comment: A colon can be used *between **independent clauses** when the second explains or illustrates the first*. But as you've correctly pointed out, ***the act of preventing passage or progress*** isn't a "clause" - it's just a ***noun phrase***. Standard orthography in English (and most other languages, I'd have thought) is to enclose that "parenthetical" defining noun phrase in brackets, OR just separate it from the preceding statement with a dash. A colon or semicolon is non-standard orthography in such contexts.

Answer (score 1):

> John was causing obstruction: the act of preventing passage or progress.

The sentence isn't a noun phrase.  The part after the colon is a noun phrase, and not a clause.

The part after the colon is a fragment.  Consider a simpler example.

> I love one kind of animal: cats.

It's fine.  Not every utterance has to be a sentence.  The sentence ends with "animal".  And then there is a single noun, which we understand to be the type of animal he loves.  It is just a noun, and not a sentence, but we understand the meaning. It doesn't need a verb.

Answer (score 0):

The colon has a number of uses, one of which is to elaborate on the previous statement, such as this from "The Devil's Dictionary" by Ambrose Bierce:

> CRITIC, n. : A person who boasts himself hard to please because nobody tries to please him.

In this case, yes, you can say what follows the colon is a noun phrase (though I'm not sure why that matters).  In other cases, the elaboration can be a complete sentence:

> The most important message of the film is this: You can't ever really go home again.

The semicolon is different; it is used to join together two complete sentences that could otherwise be separated by a period (as in this sentence).  However, in creative writing the semicolon is sometimes used as an alternative to the comma, as in this quote from "Cat's Cradle" by Kurt Vonnegut:

> Only I was going to kindergarten; Frank was going to junior high; and Father was going to work on the atom bomb.

Comment: In your first example,  would the noun phrase be [CRITIC, n,:  A person who boasts himself hard to please because nobody tries to please him]   or would it be just [A person who boasts himself hard to please because nobody tries to please him], what about the second example?

Comment: @John  as in your question, the part following the colon might be called a noun phrase (or possibly something more specific).  As I said, it's kind of a trivial question since only linguists really care about these kind of labels.  The rest of us just speak English.